# Batch- If statements based on files/websites open

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my previous question, [Batch if statements based on opening a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339516/batch-if-statements-based-on-opening-a-program), I asked how to make a batch if statement based on opening a program.

Can I make a batch-file `IF` statement based off:

1. File Paths in explorer: e.g. "C:\USERS\admin\desktop\"
2. Files: e.g. "James.csv"
3. Websites: e.g. "http://www.google.com"

To make my question a bit clearer:

```
@echo off
Set WinProcess1=D:\PFI.vbs
Set WinProcess2=c:\
Set WinProcess3=http://www.google.com

:props
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WinProcess1%" | find /C /I "%WinProcess1%" >nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 (taskkill /f /im %WinProccess1% & echo a )
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WinProcess1%" I find /C /I "%WinProcess1%" >nul 
if not ErrorLevel 1 (echo b & timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL)
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WinProcess2%" | find /C /I "%WinProcess2%" > nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 (echo destroy app & timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul )
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WinProcess3%" | find /C /I "%WinProcess3%" > nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 ( echo c & timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul )
goto props
```

This loop would simply check if `winprocess1,2, or 3` were running and `echo a,b, or c` if the file/website/path were open. If not, then it would run again.

**EDIT:** by open, I mean a program is using it. For example, if you try to rename a document via explorer while it is open, it will give you a message saying that a program (e.g)  Microsoft word is using it.

Comment: How can a program be using a web site?  Give some examples of your task.  FWIW a file can be renamed when it is in use - it will only fail if the program has it locked/open for exclusive use.

Comment: You can use `WINDOWTITLE` instead. Some application show what are opened in the Window title. But it's not 100% reliable. One track you could use, is to liste which program can open vbs;http and then check if findstr match the title name of the file or website.

Comment: Can you show what the code would then look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd case download Microsoft's [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) utility, then you can check if the file is opened:

- anywhere:

  ```
  handle "James.csv"
  ```
- in a specific program:

  ```
  handle -p excel.exe "James.csv"
  ```

Example of conditional handling:

```
handle "James.csv" | find "pid:" >nul && (echo Found) || (echo Not found)
```